# Magento2 - unable to set CRON timezone

Tags: magento2.3, crontab, magento-cron, timezone

I am having timezone = 'Asia/Jakarta' everywhere in

1. Magento admin
2. Database
3. checked in phpinfo
4. Server

But still in the CRON logs I am getting UTC time only, I need this to be in 'Asia/Jakarta' only.

I managed to check app/bootstrap.php and found

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

On commenting this line CRON runs in correct timezone, but order listing in Magento (Sales > Order) becomes in UTC now.

Tried various solutions in app/bootstrap.php (no one is working) as:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Jakarta');
date_default_timezone_set( ini_get('date.timezone') );
```

and

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
```

Any idea why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

I know is late but I was wondering about the same thing myself and found out that apparently Magento cron always runs in UTC.

just leave it like that and try remembering that if you have to read the cron as I`m pretty sure you are better off not messing with it